# Cannot access a disposed object, on a static variable?

Tags: c#, static, maui

I'm using the popup from the Maui.Community.Toolkit to display a waiting animation.

```
public static class WaitingService
{
    private static WaitingPopup waitingPopup = new();
    async public static Task ShowWaitingPopupAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            //2nd time this is called throws the exception
            await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(waitingPopup);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //cannot access a disposed object
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Exception", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
    }

    public static void HideWaitingPopup()
    {
        waitingPopup.Close();
    }
}
```

The second time around that I call ShowWaitingPopupAsync() I get the disposed object exception. My understanding is that static classes/variables are persistent, and aren't disposed of until application exit, right?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about `IDisposable`, objects are disposed when you call `Dispose()` on them. That can be done at any time, really. It has nothing to do with garbage collection (in fact, an object can be garbage collected without actually being disposed first). You'll have to figure out what object is being disposed, and who called `Dispose()` on it.

Comment: I don't believe I'm talking about `IDisposable`. I haven't called `Dispose()` anywhere. My understanding is that static variables don't get GC'd until application exit. waitingPopup is the variable that is disposed of. How can I track down what disposed of it?

Comment: Yes, and the garbage collector does not dispose objects. It only collects objects that aren't reachable, which means you can't accidentally call a method on an object that has been collected, because by then there are no remaining references to it. Disposal is a different concept: objects are manually disposed independently of reachability by the GC, and thus static fields don't magically make object non disposable. What is the call stack on that exception? What object is being disposed?

Comment: `waitingPopup.Close();` probably calls `Dispose()`.

Comment: You could add: `waitingPopup = new();` inside the `ShowWaitingPopupAsync` method.

Comment: @PoulBak You're probably right on `waitingPopup.Close();` calling `Dispose()`. I wound up putting `waitingPopup = new();` inside `ShowWaitingPopupAsync`, thanks.

Comment: Now that you know waitingPopup is not re-usable, it would be cleaner (though entirely optional) to NOT keep one alive in a static, except while it is open. `private static WaitingPopup waitingPopup;` Before use: `awaitingPopup = new();`.  In `HideWaitingPopup`: `waitingPopup.Close(); waitingPopup = null; // Close Disposes it; null so don't attempt to use again.`